# cakephp would not hash password while login but only in signup

Tags: php, cakephp, hash, authentication

I am using CakePHP 3.5. I am trying to create a simple login but I have problems:

1. I can login with the password that has not been hashed
2. My defaultpasswordhasher works... the password is actually being hashed but while login it doesn't
3. all users (user1, user2, user3) have same password "password"
4. user1 password is not hashed

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dgTnI4YzNEsxhPhcYoxqwdg02AZopA3a/view?usp=sharing]

UserController.php

```
public function login(){
      if($this->request->is('post')){
      //  $data = $this->request->getData();
        //pr($data);
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
          if($user){
            $this->Flash->success('Successful login');
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
          }else{
            $this->Flash->error(__('Please, try again.'));
          }

      }
    }


<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * UsersTable Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 */
class UsersTable extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'username' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'password' => true
    ];

    /**
     * Fields that are excluded from JSON versions of the entity.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

    protected function _setPassword($password){
      return(new  DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
login.ctp
<?= $this->Form->create();?>
<?= $this->Form->control('email'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('password'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('login');?>

<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>

AppController.php
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
            'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
        ]);
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
            'authenticate' =>[
              'Form'  => [
                'fields' => [
                  'username' =>'email',
                  'password' =>'password'

                ]
              ]
            ],
            'loginAction' =>  [
              'controller' =>'UsersTable',
              'action' =>'login'
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: Was user one created in the database? Has it been edited since creation?

Comment: yes all the users have been added into the database and no changes to the users have been made except: 1. user1 was created without hashing password then 2.password hashing was used for other users

Answer (score 0):

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html

`_setPassword` function only works when you add or edit an entity in your table.

Since you added user1 before adding _setPassword in the User Entity that why it was not hashed.

Also it doesn't hash the user1 when you login as nothing changes in the User Entity in the table.

If you want to hash user1, just edit it form the admin panel.

Comment: I am completely aware of what you have suggested. But the main problem is the system is not letting me login with or without hashing the password...Moreover I tried to create few users disabling the hashing however it still keeps hashing password for new users....I am seriously not getting why is this happening....Any suggestions???